# Fake client behaviour when mocking k8s for testing

Tags: go, testing, kubernetes, mocking, client-go

I am using the `fake` [clientset](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake) to perform some mocking in a `k8s` cli tool I am creating.

Therefore I am creating a `Job` resource

```
jobs := clientset.BatchV1().Jobs(mynamespace)
_, err = jobs.Create(context.TODO(), job, metav1.CreateOptions{})
```

The clienset has been created as follows:

```
clientset := testclient.NewSimpleClientset()
```

where

```
testclient "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake"
```

The job seems to be created, i.e. `err` is `nil` on the call above.

I then (from another function call) try to list the corresponding pods (using the exact same `clientset`)

```
podList, err = clientset.CoreV1().Pods(myNamespace).List(context.TODO(), labelOptions)
```

However the length of the corresponding list is always zero

```
len(podList.Items) = 0
```

Shouldn't the call using the `fake` clienset create all related mock resources? (such as the job's pod)

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the call using the fake clienset create all related mock resources? (such as the job's pod)

No, the fake clientset does nothing except put objects into cache.
In a real kubernetes cluster, [`JobController`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.23.6/pkg/controller/job/job_controller.go#L124) reconciles jobs and creates pods.

I suggest you testing in a real kubernetes cluster, such as [K3s](https://k3s.io/).